# Paypal Jquery Mobile Integration

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, paypal, phonegap-build

I have an app within which i am integrating a pay via Paypal option. I have integrated well only that i am experiencing an error that i am unable to resolve.

I have used this plugin;

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

In the index.js file,i have this;

```
initPaymentUI: function() {
var clientIDs = {
  "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "MY_ID",
  "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "SANDBOX_ID"
};
PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, app.onPayPalMobileInit);
```

},

Further down,i have;

```
onPayPalMobileInit: function() {
// must be called
// use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode to get look and feel of the flow
PayPalMobile.prepareToRender("PayPalEnvironmentSandbox", app.configuration(),
  app.onPrepareRender);
```

},

On my phone it authenticates well but just before i am able to pay,i get the following error;

"There was a problem setting up this payment.Please visit the Paypal website to check your account"

Any ideas on what i could be missing?

Comment: are you using the paypal option to pay or the credit card option? I would need debug-id. It can be found in the console log with a more descriptive message. can you paste here please ? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @paypal_louis i am using the paypal option. I have been unable to get the debug-id as i am not using Android Studio or eclipse currently. I am coding and deploying on my phone using Phone gap build and testing.

Comment: Since you are in Sandbox environment, did you login to your sandbox PayPal account to pay or you logged in with your Live account?

Comment: @paypal_louis i logged in to my sandbox Paypal account..

Comment: Hey @paypal_louis here is my debug ID-PayPal Debug-ID: b00a1d98b13d1

Comment: Actually its this....

{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount total"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"103b41fc215b9"}

@paypal_louis

Comment: I got it to work @paypal_louis,thank you

Comment: cool, should have posted up the error earlier which is straightforward. :) glad that it work for you and you are most welcome.

Comment: Hey @paypal_louis,one more thing,i am trying to configure PDT,i cant seem to find documentation pointing to the same on mobile. Also,my response comes back as 12-11 11:06:07.496: D/CordovaLog(27540):     "response": {
12-11 11:06:07.496: D/CordovaLog(27540):     "response_type": "payment"

Any idea why its blank?

Comment: Hey @paypal_louis your assistance will be greatly appreciated :)..

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. As the log suggested,the values i had put for the sub-total and the total weren't tallying. One was saying 50 USD and another 1USD as per the example here; https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

It is working well now working on live values as well as IPN and PDT.

Thank you @paypal_louis